# Ruby method for values from all associations

Tags: ruby, refactoring, associations

This method works, but I'm sure the performance could be greatly improved.  Also, I'm realizing how fun and awesome it is to take smelly code like this, and rubify it.  But I need a little more help to get my Ruby skills to the level to refactor something like this.

An objective can have "preassign" objectives.  These are pre-requisites that must be completed before the a student can try the objective in question.

ObjectiveStudent is the join model between an objective and a student.  It has a method called "points_all_time" that finds the student's best score on that objective.

The check_if_ready method is the one that I'm trying to refactor in this question.  It also belong to the ObjectiveStudent model. 
 It needs to check whether the student has passed ALL of the preassigns for a given objective.  If so, return true. Return false if the student has a less-than-passing score on any of the preassigns.

```
def check_if_ready
    self.objective.preassigns.each do |preassign|
        obj_stud = self.user.objective_students.find_by(objective_id: preassign.id)
        return false if obj_stud.points_all_time < 7
    end
    return true
end
```

Right now I suspect this method is making too many calls to the database.  What I'm really hoping to find is some way to look at the scores for the pre-reqs with a single db call.

Thank you in advance for any insight.

Comment: One would normally write that method to contain a single line: `objective.preassigns.all? { |preassign|
      user.objective_students.find_by(objective_id: preassign.id).points_all_time >= 7 }`. `self.` is implicit and therefore not needed. These changes would not affect performance. I don't understand the question fully so cannot suggest possible changes that could improve performance.

Comment: I think what I'm really looking for is a way to check the student's scores on all of the preassigned objectives.  But do that with fewer calls to the database than I'm currently doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should work for you:

```
def is_ready? 
  user.objective_students
   .where(objective_id: objective.preassigns.select(:id))
   .none? { |obj_stud| obj_stud.points_all_time < 7 }
end
```

We collect all the `objective_students` for the `user` where the `objective_id` is in the list of `objective.preassigns` ids. This results in one 1 query being executed.

Then we use `Enumerable#none?` to make sure that none of the `objective_students` have `points_all_time` less than 7.

You could also use the inverse `.all? { |obj_stud| obj_stud.points_all_time >= 7 }` if you wanted

Comment: I thought yours was the best.  Right now I'm going with this syntax
        user.objective_students.where(:objective => objective.preassigns).all? {|obj_stud| obj_stud.points_all_time >= 7 }.  Is it faster to use the id, as you suggest?  Or are they the same?

Comment: @JeffZivkovic they are identical as yours will be transformed into the same as mine. Yours just simply implies `id` and my explicitly states it. Rails magic and all that

Answer (score 1):

One way you could "rubify" this method is to rewrite the signature as:

```
def is_ready?
```

It is common practice to append `?` to functions that return a boolean value in Ruby. (Note: I also don't really see a reason to have the word 'check' in the declaration, but that's just an opinion).

Furthermore, if `objective_id` is the primary key for the `objective_students` model, you can simply write `objective_students.find(preassign.id)` instead of the `find_by` method.

I would also suggest having a separate method for returning a student's points (especially since I suspect you will need to get a student's points more than just once) :

```
def getPoints(preAssignId)
   return self.user.objective_students.find_by(objective_id: preAssignId).points_all_time
end
```

Then your main method can be written in a more clear, self-describing manner as:

```
 def is_ready?
    self.objective.preassigns.each {|preassign| return false if getPoints(preassign) < 7 }
    return true
 end
```

Comment: I did end up taking your advice about the method name. Thank you.